# How do I choose a web host with support for mysqli extension in PHP?

Tags: php, web-hosting, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I have designed a website running in PHP and mySQL. And I used mysqli extension instead of the normal mysql extension in PHP, so all my functions are now on mysqli. After developing a major part of the website, I started looking for suitable webhosts, and found that there are few that offer support for the mysqli extension.

I'm not sure if I have really made a mistake by preferring mysqli instead of mysql.
Could you please let me know -

1. whether mysqli support has to be confirmed with the host before I
   sign up for their web space account
2. whether mysqli support will be given by default in all PHP 5.2+
   versions
3. any good (paid, but not too expensive) webhosts with reliable
   service offering support for mysqli extension (in shared server
   more, not dedicated server)

NOTE - Mine is a small business, and I'm looking for a shared mode web host for now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try asking the webhost client support if they can host the website you've built. It's a good way to tell if they have a good customer support and you got nothing to lose.

Answer (score 1):

Support for *mysqli* should be quite common as far as i know, surely it's not a mistake to use it. Lately i was looking for a provider myself, i asked for the possibility to see a phpinfo() of a server - and got it!

Recommending a hoster would not help you very much, because you will probably want a provider in your country?